# Android first Activity not really destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity

When I was debugging my app with AndroidDeviceMonitor, I found that my app's heap was odd. After starting the app (SplashActivity -> MainActivity), the "1-byte array" has been allocated 42MB. I was sure the SplashActivity has been destroyed and I'm using LeakCanary to discover if there is any memory leakage. But I did not find anything.

Then I try to create a new SplashActiviy, just `setContentView` in `onCreate()` method without any other code.

The layout xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/splash2"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/splashlogo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I debug again and the "1-byte array" is still 42MB. Then I try to remove the `src` tag from my layout. The "1-byte array" was reduced to 35MB. So, I guess the problem is that image resources have not been recycled. Can anyone tell me more about the detail of the first launched Activity. Why doesn't it release those resources？

Comment: can I see the intent you use to start the MainActivity?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK      | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
this.finish();

also tryed remove these flags,got the same result@Modge

Comment: when you press the back button in your main activity, the splash screen is gone right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to make sure that imge image is freed up for garbage collection is set the image to null in onStop to make sure that nothing has reference to it.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

You can then use AndroidDeviceMonitor to force a garbage collection to make sure it is freed from the heap.

Comment: yes,I've tried this. It is really freed from the heap.But I'm curious about it.Why those memory are not freed after I finish the SplashActivity.Should I always have to do like `mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);`?

Comment: It could be a number of reasons. The SplashActivity didnt really finish or you are using the image somewhere else in your app thats keeping reference to it.

Comment: Also with java garbage collection it wont clear memory all the time. It will only trigger if JVM thinks it needs a garbage collection based on Java heap size.


Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html#ixzz3fTEn3RhT

Comment: And no you shouldnt have to set the image to null all the time, but its usefull sometimes

Comment: Thanks for your solution!
I have looked for memory leak carefully,but do not find anywhere.
And also after start my app,I played it for a while.Then back to MainActivity,and finish it.The "1-byte array" is still 42mb.
And tried to use AndroidDeviceMonitor to force a garbage collection,still 42mb.

Comment: Happy to help. This solution is probably good for you as you will only see the splash screen when you start the app. If it did help you pls mark it as correct.